# Replace style tag with javascript equivalent

Tags: javascript, html, css

An HTML page has an inline  block in the HEAD like so:

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {font-size: 1.2em}
</style>
```

This sets the body font size immediately when the page is loaded.

I want to replace this with something more dynamic but still on the client side.

How can I use JavaScript to set such a style that would be available and visible immediately that the page is rendered?  Body.onload is too late.  I need an equivalent to this style block, but with JavaScript.

Comment: Define "more dynamic". What do you want to affect this size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use document.head.innerHTML += in an inline script block to add HTML representing the STYLE block and style.  This is added to the DOM immediately after the SCRIPT tag that creates it.  Using backticks for the HTML template containing the font size would have made it even easier, though in the end I had to support IE 11 so backticks were out.

The solution:

```
<script>
    var fontSize = //font size retrieved here;
    document.head.innerHTML += "<style type=\"text/css\"> \nbody { font-size: ".concat(fontSize, "em } \n</style>");
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this.  I suppose that you can not insert CSS directly.

```
<p id="myCSS"></p>
<script><!--
document.getElementById("myCSS").outerHTML=[
  '<style type="text/css">'
 ,'body { font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.5em }'
 ,'<\/style>'].join('\r');
-->
</script>
```

Note that some CSS settings are hard to recovery to it's original one. With the css value `unset` you can do that, but IE does not support it.  In such cases, maybe 'try and error' is the best you can do.

Comment: `<script><!--` Interesting mix of HTML5 and HTML3.2 there...

Comment: It's for preventing the JS code from being filtered out by server.  If they don't, you can remove the `<!--` and `-->`

Comment: I've never heard of a server filtering out JS code just because it wasn't wrapped in HTML comments...

Comment: Actually, I've met one: the mobile site of 'pixnet.net'. I've to paste this code for custom my CSS for mobile. They clean up the `<style>` and `<link>` of non-CDN, and `<script>`.